# Unable to cross-compile Python-2.7.18 for x86,uclibc

Tags: python, linux, cross-compiling, libc, uclibc

I'm trying to cross-compile Python 2.7.18 for an x86,uclibc machine using a crosstool-ng example toolchain. The commands used are the following:

`CONFIG_SITE=config.site CC=/home/msainz/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc CXX=/home/msainz/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc-g++ AR=/home/msainz/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc-ar RANLIB=/home/msainz/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc-ranlib READELF=/home/msainz/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc-readelf LDFLAGS="-L/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/lib -L/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/usr/lib" CFLAGS="-I/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/usr/include -I/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/include" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/usr/include -I/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/include" ./configure --enable-shared --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc --build=x86_64 --disable-ipv6 --prefix=/home/msainz/Projects/python2_top_uclibc/`

followed by

`PATH=$PATH:/home/msainz/Projects/python2_top_glibc/bin/ make`

and

`PATH=$PATH:/home/msainz/Projects/python2_top_glibc/bin/ make install`

Execution ends with the following error:

`fi /home/msainz/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc -L/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/lib -L/home/msainz/Projects/Selene/WP3/local/uclibc/base_rootfs/usr/lib -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \ Modules/python.o \ -L. -lpython2.7 -ldl  -lpthread   -lm   _PYTHON_PROJECT_BASE=/home/msainz/Projects/Python-2.7.18 _PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM=linux2-x86_64 PYTHONPATH=./Lib:./Lib/plat-linux2 python -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars ;\ if test $? -ne 0 ; then \ echo "generate-posix-vars failed" ; \ rm -f ./pybuilddir.txt ; \ exit 1 ; \ fi python: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory generate-posix-vars failed make: *** [Makefile:523: pybuilddir.txt] Error 1`

`python2_top_glibc` dir contains a previous Python-2.7.18 installation but for native glibc which was compiled perfectly. libc.so.0 is in fact in the base_rootfs of target system, which is being linked in ./configure stage. I'm stuck at this at the moment. Any clue will be appreciated. Any additional info will be supplied on demand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format the messages such that they are not lumped into one long line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> python: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is a run-time loader error. You are trying to run a `python` executable that is linked against that `libc.so.0`.

If this executable can actually run in your host environment, you can enable it by adding your base_rootfs library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Otherwise, you need to use your host python executable in this step of the build process, or disable it altogether.

Comment: But, as far as I understand, the python executable which is trying to run is the one which is being compiled. The executable in PATH is linked against libc.so.6, I've checked it. If i add the libc.so.0 path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, a different error happens: `python: Relink \`/home/msainz/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/x86_64-unknown-linux-uclibc/sysroot/lib/libc.so.0' with \`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol \`stpcpy'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @m.dorian "the python executable which is trying to run is the one which is being compiled" Yes that's exactly what I mean. "The executable in PATH is linked against libc.so.6" Perhaps you want to run that instead. "a different error happens" Maybe your cross-built python executable cannot run on your host machine at all, I have no idea what cross-built uclibc can or cannot do. Messages that contain "for IFUNC symbol" are googleable but I have not tried to investigate.

Comment: Perhaps try to add your sysroot/lib and run `ldd python` on your compiled executable. You should not get any host shared libraries in the output. If you do get any, you need to have these libraries cross-built too, and add them to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This is not a guarantee of anything though.